# C++: "No match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' and 'Complex')"

Tags: c++, oop, templates, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to compare and print two Complex objects using a custom Max function in C++. The Complex class has overloaded operator>> and operator<<, and I have also defined a bool operator> to compare two Complex objects based on their magnitudes. However, when I attempt to use the Max<Complex> function to find the maximum of two Complex objects and print the result, I encounter the error:

> "No match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' and 'Complex')".

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Complex
{
    int real;
    int img;
public:
    bool operator>(Complex &a)
    {
        if(this->real*this->real + this->img*this->img > a.real*a.real + a.img*a.img)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, Complex &e);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Complex &e);
};
istream& operator>>(istream &in, Complex &e)
{
    in >> e.real;
    in >> e.img;
    return in;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Complex &e)
{
    out << e.real << "+ i" << e.img;
    return out;
}

template<class T> T Max(T a,T b)
{
    return (a>b)? a: b;
}

int main()
{
    Complex a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << Max<Complex>(a,b);
}
```

I can't find the reason behind this error.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the function `Max` returns a temporary object

```
template<class T> T Max(T a,T b)
{
    return (a>b)? a: b;
}
```

But the `operator <<` expects an lvalue reference according to its declaration

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Complex &e);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You may not bind a temporary object to a non-constant lvalue reference.

Declare the operator like

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Complex &e);

//...

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Complex &e)
{
    out << e.real << "+ i" << e.img;
    return out;
}
```

that is specifying the qualifier `const` for the referenced type of the second parameter.